# Get Lookup column value in SharePoint online search results using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, lookup-column, sharepoint-search

We have a SharePoint list `Products` with columns `Title, DisplayName, etc..` and document library `Product Documents`. The `Products` list is the lookup for the `Product Documents`. we created a results source for the Sharepoint search that will returns search results from the  `Product Documents` document library. I want to get the `DisplayName` in the search results. I created a new managed property `ProductDisplayName` and mapped to the crawled property (`ows_DisplayName)` based on the internal column name. I am trying to get the column value using the C#  CSOM

```
KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
keywordQuery.SourceId = new Guid(SearchSourceId);                        
keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("ListItemID");
keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("ProductDisplayName");
var   results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

But I am getting the null values for the column in the search results
Can we get the lookup columns values in the search results ? or is there any workaround for the same.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

**Update:**

I reindexed the site, Document Library and waited for the 24 hours for crawling. 
I tried to map the crawled property to `RefinableString03`, but no use.